# Sticky Navbar still moves

Tags: html, css

On my landing page, with a position: sticky nav bar, The navbar will stay at the top of the page but it does not stay completely stationary while scrolling

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jcrainey/pen/rNGLyOQ

I've tried setting a fixed height to .sticky but it just adds space to the bottom of the navbar. Any thoughts on how to make it stay completely stationary?

```css
   body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: white;
        color: black;
        font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .sticky {
        background-color: white;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        height: 60px;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        position: sticky;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    .links {
        font-size: 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: gray;
        padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    
    }
    
    li:nth-child(1) {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: -20px;
    }
    
    .links:hover {
        color: black;
    }
    
    .intro {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
        font-size: 35px;
    }
    
    .scroll {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: white;
        height: 2000px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="landingpage.css">
        <title>Landing Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sticky">
            <nav>
                <ul class= "navbar">
                    <li><a class = "links" href = "#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a class = "links" href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a class = "links" href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class = "intro">
            <h1>JC Rainey</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll">just to show what happens when you scroll</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

.navbar has inherited margins.

Set a `margin: 0` on .navbar and give it a height.

```css
.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
}
```

You should be able to remove the height from .sticky too.

Comment: thats great! thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to adjust the height, or set the top padding. The reason why your `navbar` was moving is that it will move towards the top until any "explicitly defined" `margin`, or any "existing `margin`" is completely gone. You need to only add margin: 0; to your `.navbar` element in your style-sheet, like in the snippet below.

Just a tip. If you press F12 to open the tools, and find the nav-bar element in the HTML that is rendered in the chrome dev-tools, click on it, and it will show you what youre padding, margin, and border all are set too.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}

.sticky {
    background-color: white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
}

.navbar {
    position: sticky;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top:0;
}

.links {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;

}

li:nth-child(1) {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.links:hover {
    color: black;
}

.intro {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.scroll {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add `padding-top: 1px;` to `.sticky`. The reason: The included `ul` (`.navbar`) has default top and bottom `margin`s, which are not included in the "sticky" part (aka "collapsing margins"). Adding just one pixel of padding-top to the parent prevents that.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}

.sticky {
    background-color: white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.navbar {
    position: sticky;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
}

.links {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;

}

li:nth-child(1) {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.links:hover {
    color: black;
}

.intro {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.scroll {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="landingpage.css">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sticky">
        <nav>
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a class = "links" href = "#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a class = "links" href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li><a class = "links" href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class = "intro">
        <h1>JC Rainey</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll">just to show what happens when you scroll</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here.

1st, you have `position: sticky` in 2 places: `.sticky` and `.navbar`. I removed it from your `.navbar`. 2nd, your `ul` is inheriting browser styles. (It's often useful to use a CSS reset to remove these: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/.) I removed the margin from your `ul` and gave it a `1em` padding. 3rd, I removed your negative margin on your first `li`. Is this what you're looking for?

```css
body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: white;
        color: black;
        font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .sticky {
        background-color: white;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        height: 60px;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1em;
    }
    
    .links {
        font-size: 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: gray;
        padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    
    }
    
    li:nth-child(1) {
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .links:hover {
        color: black;
    }
    
    .intro {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
        font-size: 35px;
    }
    
    .scroll {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: white;
        height: 2000px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="landingpage.css">
        <title>Landing Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sticky">
            <nav>
                <ul class= "navbar">
                    <li><a class = "links" href = "#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a class = "links" href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a class = "links" href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class = "intro">
            <h1>JC Rainey</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll">just to show what happens when you scroll</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```